# Git:How to commit changed file content done from commit_msg hook

Tags: git

Objective: 
(1) The git commit message (with -m switch, or using a editor) has to be put in the
committed file. We have a comment block at the start of each source file, 
which has these commit messages in a line in a particular format.

Problem in implementation:
(2) I have a commit_msg hook script where I insert the commit comments by the user 
to the committed files (in the starting comment block). 
But after the commit the files are again marked as modified. 
When I do a diff I see the last changes I made to the file from my hook script, 
are the modification, which did not get committed.

Is there a git command option which will let me amend the commit changes, 
which I made from the commit_msg hook?

I thought I cannot use pre-commit and prepare-commit-msg hooks, because, I need the users
commit comments, which he puts using the popped up editor at the time of commit, 
or from the -m switch. This action happens after the above 2 hooks are called,
so my only option was commit-msg, post-commit hook is too late.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
sguha.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the commit messages inside the file will only lead to the file size ballooning over the course of the project. What exactly is the need to have these messages at the top of the file?

Why can't you use `git log <that file> --oneline` instead to see all the commits made to this file?

This would let you see the commits *just* for that file.

Comment: That is a very good option, I would like to follow also, but I have no choice. This software group is doing the same with clearcase, and want to move to git, with as little change as possible. Thanks for your comments. But I am looking for the solution as depicted above.